# Python modules threading and turtle unexpected behavior on Mac OS 13.5.1

Tags: python, macos, python-multithreading, python-turtle, nsexception

I'm working on a script to help me grade student homework assignments. They may contain long-running turtle tasks in addition to other code. I want to run that code inside a local scope where I can override various turtle functions to make the code easier to grade. When I tried to do so, I encountered unexpected errors.

I want to process the turtle tasks and run my unit test suite. I created the following small example minimum_reproducible_example to showcase my issue.

```py
#mre.py
import turtle
import threading

def run_turtle_code():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(100)
        t.right(90)
    turtle.done()

def run_turtle_in_thread():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_turtle_code)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_turtle_in_thread()
```

When I try to run the above code example in any of the latest released Python versions for 3.6-3.10, I get the same error:

```
2023-09-26 11:42:25.542 python[6422:91998] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80cc8018a __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80c7a642b objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80cca82f6 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   AppKit                              0x00007ff80fcc9e7e -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 307
    4   AppKit                              0x00007ff80fcb6394 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1227
    5   AppKit                              0x00007ff80fcb5ec2 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001075078f8 TkMacOSXMakeRealWindowExist + 692
    7   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000107507519 TkWmMapWindow + 63
    8   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000107474cc3 MapFrame + 59
    9   libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000107250520 TclServiceIdle + 75
    10  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000107234c20 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 341
    11  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001074f96da TkpInit + 762
    12  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010746d59c Initialize + 2402
    13  _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x0000000106c17ce4 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    14  _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x0000000106c125ba Tkapp_New + 602
    15  _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x0000000106c11ee1 _tkinter_create + 561
    16  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cf2de2 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 178
    17  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d96ef4 call_function + 356
    18  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93bc9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28105
    19  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d97f34 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3204
    20  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb28fc _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236
    21  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d96ef4 call_function + 356
    22  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93bc9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28105
    23  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    24  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb1c8c _PyObject_FastCallDict + 220
    25  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb3343 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
    26  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d0eb58 slot_tp_init + 184
    27  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d09c94 type_call + 292
    28  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb1e59 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 377
    29  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d97020 call_function + 656
    30  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93c6a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28266
    31  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    32  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb1c8c _PyObject_FastCallDict + 220
    33  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb3343 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
    34  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d0eb58 slot_tp_init + 184
    35  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d09c94 type_call + 292
    36  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb1e59 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 377
    37  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d97020 call_function + 656
    38  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93c6a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28266
    39  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    40  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d96ef4 call_function + 356
    41  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93c6a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28266
    42  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d97f34 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3204
    43  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb28fc _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236
    44  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb1c8c _PyObject_FastCallDict + 220
    45  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb3343 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
    46  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d0eb58 slot_tp_init + 184
    47  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d09c94 type_call + 292
    48  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb1e59 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 377
    49  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d97020 call_function + 656
    50  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93bc9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28105
    51  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    52  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb2174 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
    53  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93ed3 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28883
    54  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    55  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d96ef4 call_function + 356
    56  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93ba5 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28069
    57  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    58  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d96ef4 call_function + 356
    59  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106d93ba5 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28069
    60  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb278b function_code_fastcall + 171
    61  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb51c3 method_vectorcall + 323
    62  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106cb2174 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
    63  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106e3926b t_bootstrap + 75
    64  libpython3.8.dylib                  0x0000000106de9ff9 pythread_wrapper + 25
    65  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80cb2d1d3 _pthread_start + 125
    66  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80cb28bd3 thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm running Mac OS: 13.5.1
Any help would be appreciated. I don't see this as a multi-threading issue, but I didn't see a tag for the built-in python threading module.

Comment: How would your script actually verify that the code worked and grade it? Please provide context to avoid the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), because there may be a better approach to solving your actual problem of grading students than using threading like this.

Comment: Single threaded version of your code actually runs. Did you try it? So, this _is_ a a multi-threading issue in your code.